# How many times does with clause query runs

Tags: oracle11g

I am having a query, which needs to use multiple times in actual query. So i put that reusable query in with clause.

The below query is just an example purpose only.

Here my doubt is, How many times does a query used in **cte1** with clause executes?

In below query, cte1 used two times. So the query used in cte1 is executes only once or two times.

```
with cte1 as
(
   select ename, eno, deptno, sal from emp where sal >= 2000
)
select x.ename,x.eno,y.deptno, 'B' Grade
from cte1 x, dept y
on x.deptno = y.deptno
and e.sal between 2000 and 4000
union all
select x.ename,x.eno,y.deptno, 'C'
from cte1 x, dept y
on x.deptno = y.deptno
and e.sal > 4000
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, a CTE that is referenced more than once will be materialized. Otherwise the CTE will behave like an inline view

Answer (score 0):

[CTE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html) is creating temporary table, so the SQL inside is executed once

> temporary result set that exists within the scope of a single statement and that can be referred to later within that statement, possibly multiple times